# Wordpress - Displaying a nav menu from functions.php using hooks

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to call a menu to display in a certain place of my page. The theme has a hook above the content that I want to use as the place to display the menu. I do not want to modify the core files of the theme, so the goal is to achieve this using only functions.php modifications

I am adding the following code to my functions.php

On my menu panel, I already have assigned the menu "categories" to the "catmenu" theme location.

```
register_nav_menu( 'catmenu', 'Categories Menu' );

//adds category menu on single post pages
function add_catmenu()
{
wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'categories'); }

add_action('thematic_abovecontent', 'add_catmenu');
```

Wordpress doesn't seem to be getting it. I get a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:...\functions.php on line 253

Line 253 is the one that has the wp_nav_menu call.

I have been trying modifications of this, like echoing that whole line 253, but again I get errors or it doesn't work.

I don't know how to accomplish this. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis:

```
wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'categories')); }
```